# Android SQLite query WHERE clause

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

Is this correct way to form SQLite query with WHERE and its arguments, because I am getting error the bind value at index 4 is null.

```
public Cursor getBankomatLocation(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "Naslov", "Kraj"};
    String sqlTables="Bankomati_db";
    String sqlWhere = "Banka=? AND(Posta BETWEEN ? AND ? OR Kraj = ?)";
    String [] args ={selectedBank, selectedPostaPod, selectedPostaNad, selectedKraj};
    Log.d("getBankomatLocation", "selectedBank" + selectedBank);
    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c =qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlWhere, args, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

SQL statement: SELECT Naslov, Kraj FROM Bankomati_db Where Banka = SelectedBank AND (Posta BETWEEN selectedPostaPod AND SelectedPostaNad OR kraj = selectedKraj)

Error msg:

```
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jenko.bojan.a2/com.jenko.bojan.a2.BankomatiActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 4 is null
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 4 is null
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:164)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jenko.bojan.a2.MyDatabase.getBankomatLocation(MyDatabase.java:81)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jenko.bojan.a2.BankomatiActivity.Location(BankomatiActivity.java:61)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.jenko.bojan.a2.BankomatiActivity.onCreate(BankomatiActivity.java:47)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
01-15 13:26:19.738 2682-2682/com.jenko.bojan.a2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Judging by the error the selectedKraj var is null, you should make sure the args are non null.

Comment: Could you post the error message / exception, please?

Comment: I think that index 4 means entire args not just selectedKraj as Cata suggested

Comment: You did not pass the 4th index in `String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "Naslov", "Kraj"};`. And I'd rewrite the WHERE like `String sqlWhere = "Banka = ? AND (Posta BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR Kraj = ?";`

Comment: Logcat shows error at this line :`Cursor c =qb.query(db, sqlSelect, sqlWhere, args, null, null, null);`